# Nested loops forvalues in Stata

Tags: stata

I'm trying to simulate some data. To do so, I am looping the data generating process the number of times need. I want to nest that loop within another to change the value of a variable, but I'm always getting a "invalid syntax" error.

The code looks like this:

```
forvalues i = -2.5(1/10)2.5 {
    forvalues j = 1 / 100 {
        clear
        set obs = 100
        set seed = 87689
        gen x runiform(0,1)
        gen u1 rnormal(0,1)
        gen Y = `i'*x + u1
    
        qui reg Y x
        
    }
}
```

Anyone knows where is the error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors!

This will run:

```
forvalues i = -25(1)25 {
    local i2 = `i'/10 
    forvalues j = 1 / 100 {
        clear
        set obs 100
        set seed 87689
        gen x = runiform(0,1)
        gen u1 = rnormal(0,1)
        gen Y = `i2'*x + u1
        qui reg Y x
    }
}
```

The repeated `clear`s are pointless. This is slightly better style.

```
clear 
set obs 100  
gen x = . 
gen u1 = . 
gen Y = . 

forvalues i = -25(1)25 {
    local i2 = `i'/10 
    forvalues j = 1 / 100 {
        set seed 87689
        replace x = runiform(0,1)
        replace u1 = rnormal(0,1)
        replace Y = `i2'*x + u1
        qui reg Y x
    }
}
```

The most subtle error here is that looping over non-integers is fraught with difficulty. `forvalues` will not evaluate `1/10` on the fly for you, surprising though that may seem. See https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0051 for more.

Otherwise `help set` and `help generate` show that you have `=` signs where illegal and no `=` signs where essential.

Otherwise the code does 5100 regressions and does nothing with the results. Perhaps that is the next step.